# I have a problem with addon Spark AR Toolkit in Blender

Tags: scripting, add-on

I have a problem in Blender 2.9. WhenI click anywhere in the workspace and an error appears.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\2.90\scripts\startup\bl_operators\wm.py", line 1662, in execute owner_id = workspace.owner_ids[self.owner_id] KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Spark AR Toolkit" not found'

location: :-1
```

How fix it?

Comment: Suggest you ask the addon developers since it's not built in to Blender! I assume you have the latest version? - The website says: "Older versions of Spark AR Toolkit are not compatible with Blender 2.9. If you downloaded the Toolkit before 25 September 2020, make sure to download it again from this page."